# Аналог Stream.reduce java

Tags: java, java-stream

Привет) Я никак не могу найти аналог методу reduce в java stream api, только у этого аналога по сравнению с основным методом должно быть одно отличие - мне нужно избежать операции сведения всего потока в какой-то один объект. Возможно, можно было бы использовать Collectors(поскольку на выходе мне нужен список), но я не представляю, как это можно провернуть (параметр identity все ломает)

Пример того, чего бы мне очень хотелось добиться:

Предположим, у меня есть список строк, из которых мне нужно в одной операции потока замапить их в объект, при этом, если следующий элемент удовлетворяет какому-то условию, прикрутить его к первому. О чем я:

```
class SomeProperty {
String someField;
Srring property;
//allArgsConstructor
} 

//THEN

List<SomeProperty> list = List.of(...elements...).stream()
.reduce((x,y)->{
    if(y.equals("i am property!") {
       return new SomeProperty(x, y) ;
    } else {
       return new SomeProperty(x, "default") ;
    } 
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Как то в этом духе)
У кого есть идеи, поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Comment: Наверное Вам нужно разработать свой коллектор `java.util.stream.Collector<T,A,R>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Развитие предидущего ответа:

```
enum Data {
    FIELD, PROPERTY
}

static class SomeProperty {
    private String someField;
    private List<String> property = new ArrayList<>();

    public SomeProperty(String someField, List<String> property) {
        this.someField = someField;
        this.property = property;
    }

    public SomeProperty(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeProperty{" +
                "someField='" + someField + '\'' +
                ", property=" + String.join(", ", property) +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<SomeProperty> result = List.of(FIELD, PROPERTY, FIELD, FIELD, PROPERTY, PROPERTY, PROPERTY)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    LinkedList::new,
                    (acc, v) -> {
                        if (v == FIELD) {
                            acc.offer(new SomeProperty(v.name()));
                        } else {
                            Optional.ofNullable(acc.peek()).ifPresent(p -> p.property.add(v.name()));
                        }
                    },
                    (acc1, acc2) -> {
                        acc1.addAll(acc2);
                        return acc1;
                    }));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

reduce не очень-то подходит для подобных случаев, поскольку его аккумулятор должен быть того же типа, что и текущий элемент. Потому я предлогаю пользоваться для таких случаев `Collector.of`

Логика такая:
Если текущий элемент - Field, создаем новый SomeProperty с properties по умолчанию (в этом примере пустая коллекция) и загоняем в очередь.
В ином случае, берем верх очереди (если он есть) и добавляем ему property

Блок:

```
(acc1, acc2) -> {
    acc1.addAll(acc2);
    return acc1;
 }
```

Нужен только для случая, когда используется parallelStream для комбинирования параллельных результатов и в данном случае может быть проигнорирован.

Comment: это лучшее что я видела - не знала, что коллектор так умеет. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий вариант. Выглядит страшно, но функциональная парадигма вся об этом.

```
package yourpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static yourpackage.Main.Data.FIELD;
import static yourpackage.Main.Data.PROPERTY;

public class Main {

    enum Data {
        FIELD, PROPERTY
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          List<List<Data>> result =
              List.of(FIELD, PROPERTY, FIELD, FIELD, PROPERTY, PROPERTY, PROPERTY)
              .stream()
              .map(d -> List.of(List.of(d)))
              .reduce(new ArrayList<List<Data>>(),
                  (fieldList, d) -> {
                  if (d.get(0).get(0) == FIELD) {
                      var list = new ArrayList<Data>();
                      list.add(d.get(0).get(0));
                      fieldList.add(list);
                  } else {
                      fieldList
                          .get(fieldList.size() - 1)
                          .add(d.get(0).get(0));
                  }
                  return fieldList;
                  });

          System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Вывод следующий
`[[FIELD, PROPERTY], [FIELD], [FIELD, PROPERTY, PROPERTY, PROPERTY]]`

Здесь и далее *"массив массивов"* (тип ответа) буду обозначать как *"супермассив"*

В кратце: мы хотим получить супермассив, где в каждом массиве первый элемент *FIELD* а следующие *PROPERTY*. Для этого мы оборачивем каждое значение в два массива, лишь затем, чтобы их тип совпал с супермассивом (строгая типизация в Java, мда). При *reduce*, если вновь пребывший элемент - `[[FIELD]]`, то мы создаем новый массив вида `[FIELD]` и добавляем в конец супермассива, а если `[[PROPERTY]]`, то мы берем последний массив из супермассива, который представляет последний *FIELD* и его свойства, и добавляем еще одно.

Так же замечу, что код падает, если первый элемент есть *FIELD*.

Этот пример легко сводится к вашей задаче, достаточно сделать один [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: хм, надо проверить. Спасибо! если что еще ткну галочку

Comment: не, не прокатит. Хочет стрингу вместо объекта(

Comment: Пробовали сначала скомпоновать строчки как выше, а потом замапить в SomeProperty?